# Are partitions pre-allocated to executors or dynamically allocated?

Tags: apache-spark

In a call of foreachPartitions/mapPartitions, there are two possible allocation strategy:

1. Pre-allocate all partitions to different executors, i.e., if I have 1000 partitions and 10 executors, then each executor gets exactly 100 partitions.
2. Whenever an executor is ready, allocate a new partition to it, i.e., if some partitions run slowly, the executor may get fewer partitions and others get more.

Which strategy is actually used by spark?

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple answer to this question. Exact allocation of executors depends on the cluster manager (standalone, YARN, Mesos and more to come) and the number of configuration option, some of which way not applicable to all managers:

- `spark.deploy.spreadOut` - either round robin or consolidation to a minimum number of nodes.
- `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled` - enable allocation depending on the workload.
- `spark.speculation` - enable speculative execution for slow tasks.

This can be further affected by the data locality (further affected by `spark.locality.wait`) and runtime events (failures, timeouts) and application specific parameters (like preferred locations) and DAG / execution plan (in certain contexts Spark will prefer co-location of partitions).